# Setting a config value dynamically in the controller in Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, file-upload, configuration, image-upload

I'm trying to upload an image using Codegniter's Upload Library, the image should be uploaded to a directory which is created and returned by the model, do the upload directory changed every time, this is the code I'm supposed to use to change the config upload array:

```
    if ($_FILES['image']['size']!=0) {
                $path = $this->homeModel->createDirectories($id);
                $this->config->load('upload');
                $this->config->set_item('upload', array('upload_path' => $path));
                // I've also used
                // $this->config->set_item('upload_path', $path);

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('image'))
                echo $this->upload->display_errors();
                else {
                    $image = $this->upload->data();
                    $data['image'] = $image['file_name'];
                }        
            }
```

but it doesn't seem to work. The upload_path doesn't change, the image is still uploaded in the path I've specified in config/upload.php file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
if ($_FILES['image']['size']!=0) {

   $path = $this->homeModel->createDirectories($id);
   $this->config->load('upload', TRUE);
   $config = $this->config->item('upload');
   $config['upload_path'] = $path;
   $this->upload->initialize($config);

   //etc.
}
```